# How to make a gradient in the x axis with hair particles?

Tags: node-editor, particles, eevee-render-engine

I want to make make the gradient from top to bottom of the grass but instead it looks like this:
[image: badgrass]

This is my node settings
[image: nodes]

this is a painted version of what i want to achieve
[image: painted good grass]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this node chain: *(Input) Texture Coordinate (Generated* output) > *(Vector) Mapping* (even though it's not useful here) > *(Converter) Separate XYZ > ColorRamp > Diffuse (or Principled BSDF) > Material Output*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks the trick was to use an object on the particle system and put the gradient on the object instead of the terrain.